# Save As shapefile OGR error

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, save

I'm working with shapefiles of water protection areas (of Germany) to find out weather or not somme geocoded adresses are inside of these areas.

Every federal state delivers shapefiles in a different CRS and I usually solve this by choosing "Save As" to project them in my Project CRS (EPSG 4326) before further processing them.

The file for "Baden Würtemberg" however aborts with an Error message when I try to do this.

Link to the source of the shapefile:
http://udo.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/public/pages/url/show.xhtml?url=http%3A%2F%2Frips-dienste.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de%2Frips%2Fripsservices%2Fapps%2Fgeodatenexport%2Fudo%2Fdownload.aspx%3Fid%3D32

Error message when "Save As" is used:

> Export in Vektordatei schlug fehl. Fehler: Objektschreibfehler:
>   Objektgeometrie nicht importiert (OGR-Fehler: ) Objektgeometrie nicht
>   ...
>   importiert (OGR-Fehler: )Abbruch nach 1001 Fehlern

translated:

> Export to shapefile failed. Error: object writing error:
>   Object geometry not imported (OGR-Error: ) 
>   abort on error number 1001

---

What I tried so far:

- I can "Save As" other shapefiles from and to the chosen directory. I also tried creating a new QGIS project with the shapefile directly on the desktop (so its not a permissen problem).
- "Save as" doesn't work when not changing the CRS as well
- I checked with "validate geometry" and eliminated all the errors by deleting duplicate nodes and overlapping areas of the shapefile. Different shapefiles with non-valid geometry can be saved too.
- Save to a file without critical signs like spaces, umlaute (ä,ö,ü,ß).

Any ideas where this error comes from?

Am I missing out some problem with the original shapefile?

Maybe you could try to reproduce this to find out if the problem is in the original shapefile itself or caused by my GIS-configuration.

---

Using QGIS-2.10.1 on Win7. I'am stuck with these specs for now, will try with newer QGIS version and report back later.

---

Back home it works with QGiS2.8.6. Maybe there is an bug only in 2.10.1 or, more likely, I missed something.

Comment: Which QGIS version and platform are you using? I can confirm this works fine for QGIS 2.16.1 for Windows 7 64-bit. Here is an [image](http://imgur.com/a/9gsqz).

Comment: Did try it with 2.14.7 on Win7 64bi tand the downloaded data and can´t reproduce the error. Maybe you have a corrupt installation?

Comment: Did you save to a different filename? It works for me even with QGIS 2.8.3.

Comment: Maybe the source-shapefile still had an Umlaut "ü"... I only checked the filename I gave the new layer.... thanks Andrej

Comment: @Papierwolf even saving as `BaWü.shp` works for me.

Comment: @AndreJ thanks for your effort. Maybe the problem occures due to the QGis-Version  I am using. Will try to reproduce this on another PC with the same version soon. Also I found a second shapefile that leads to the same error.